# Wrong shading after Shade Flat

Tags: edit-mode

how to fix this? This happened when I used Flat Shading on top faces[image]

Comment: Did you try going to object data properties(vertex group section)>Normals>auto smooth? If this isn't the issue you may have extruded those top faces. If that's not the issue then you can just redo your mesh, it isn't that detailed yet. I would approach this by either using a Boolean modifier with a smaller cylinder or insetting both end faces of a cylinder then deleting the insets and then bridging the edges at each end.

Comment: **Did you try going to object data properties(vertex group section)>Normals>auto smooth.** This fixed my issue thanks)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How2Fix: **Object data properties(vertex group section)>Normals>auto smooth**

Comment: oh i see! Ill post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

object data properties(vertex group section)>Normals>auto smooth|| This will fix the issue.